# JSpinner get Max Min Value

Tags: java, swing, spinner

I can get the current value by using getValue(), but is it possible to get the Maximum and Minimum allowable value for the JSpinner? Can't find method such as getMax() or getMin() for JSpinner from the docs.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerModel.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only some SpinnerModel's have the concept of min/max values.

So you need to look at the specific model you are using for your spinner. For example,

1. SpinnerNumberModel
2. SpinnerDateModel

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some casting to access the properties, assuming the spinners were created with the specified model.

```
double max = (Double) ((SpinnerNumberModel) jSpinner.getModel()).getMaximum();
double min = (Double) ((SpinnerNumberModel) jSpinner.getModel()).getMinimum();
```