# How to get JSpinner min and max values in order to set a random value

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I have a function that will use JSpinner.setValue() to assign a random value within the spinner's bounds. Of course, I need to know the spinner's minimum and maximum values, which are already assigned. At this point, I'm cycling through the entire spinner to determine these values. Is there a better way to find them? Something like

```
JSpinner.getModel().getMaxValue();
```

I have already read through similar questions including this one: [JSpinner get Max Min Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226702/jspinner-get-max-min-value), but it didn't answer my question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [How to Use Spinners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about numerical values. In such case you should use `NumberSpinnerModel` - this class already has method you requested: `getMaximum()` and `getMinimum()`.

`JSpinner.getModel()` returns `SpinnerModel` so you will have to cast it to `SpinnerNumberModel`. This is ofcourse if you are really using this model with your spinner - cast will fail otherwise.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find this anywhere online, so I hope your answer can help somebody else in my predicament.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of getting the min/max value from a JSpinner where the min/max values have been set as Double values.

```
// Get Minimum and Maximum values from jSpinner's Model 
    double max = (Double) ((SpinnerNumberModel)    jSpinner.getModel()).getMaximum();//MAX_ALLOWED
    double min = (Double) ((SpinnerNumberModel) jSpinner.getModel()).getMinimum();//LOWEST_ALLOWED
```